# Page Post Back Error when Java script Alert ok button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using Javascript for Show alert in Page That please Fill Valid Address When check Latitude Logitude

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redit", "alert('Please first fill all address details.'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Home.aspx';", true);
```

When this Alert Show if We Click ok then page is Postback and Empty all Othe Tesxboxes

Answer (score 0):

its not make post back, but page reload because you have right after the `window.location=` that say to the browser to load that page again and naturally everything lost.

Keep only the alert, and change if you like something on code behind, because anyway you use the code behind to show that alert.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that after alert you change the current location using the following code:

```
window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Home.aspx';"
```

If the problem is reproduce if you delete this lines?